# Node JS and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008r2-express, node-mssql

I want to use NodeJS to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database.
I've looked around at what NPM has to offer. Have tried `mssql`, `mssql-simple` and node-SQLServer.

Some of them can be installed some do not. And those who do, will not access SQL Server.

Error when using `mssql`:

> [Error: connection to .\SQLEXPRESS:1433 - failed Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT]
>   var sql = require('mssql');
>   var config = {
>     user: 'root',
>     password: 'xxx',
>     server: '.\SQLEXPRESS',
>     database: 'test'
>   }
>   var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
>      console.log(err);
>   });

If there is anyone who has got something to work between NodeJS and SQL Server Express? Which module and version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that i did not have TCP/IP Enabled.
How to check and Enable MSSQL TCP/IP [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
Next you do not have to use "server: '.\SQLEXPRESS'" after enabled TCP/IP 127.0.0.1 works fine!

Comment: Hi Krister, which module did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

you could also just put 'localhost' as your server.

Answer (score 0):

// const sql = require("msnodesqlv8");

USE THIS

npm i msnodesqlv8

it is easy to use

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).